# How to send a message from an RSU (Omnet++ VEINS)?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins, transport, vehicle-routing

I am trying to implement functionality for RSU message forwarding to neighboring RSUs upon receiving a message from a car.

When looking at the RSU node, there is only a *veinsradioIn* gate which forwards into the NIC *radioIn* gate. At the RSU application type implementation side (*DemoBaseApplLayer*), I see that the *handleLowerMsg* function will cast the message among the message option types (bsm, wsa, wsm). I do not see something for sending a message. Also, I do not see a *veinsradioOut* gate in the RSU module.

How can I send messages from the RSU? And to take it a step further, how can I distinguish a message that is sent from an RSU compared to a node (car)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DemoBaseApplLayer extends another class. In that class, there are the functions to send down and send down with delay.